# How to swap 2 Dictionary objects without making copy in C#

Tags: c#

all:

I have 2 Dictionary objects d1 and d2. They are created separately at beginning, and contents are added to them separately. After some processing, I want to do following things:

- Make d1 reference d2;
- Make d2 reference to a new object.

I am C# beginner and only find below way to do this job:

```
d1 = new Dictionary<int, int>(d2);
d2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Can I do it more efficiently like C++ way, like below? Pseudo code:

```
d1 = d2;
d2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `new Dictionary<int, int>(d2)` call actually creates a new instance of a Dictionary and copies the members over. This creates a new object reference (so newD1 != oldD2) and may not be what you intend.

Comment: @David It is ok as long as content is same. By the way, is this copy deep or shallow, meaning copy only references of KeyValuePair objects?

Comment: it's a deep copy. According to Red Gate Reflector (an essential tool) the constructor repeatedly calls newDict.Add( pair.Key, pair.Value ) for each KeyValuePair instance, so in that respect it's a deep copy of the keys and values (but not the key-value pairs themselves).

Comment: @David That information is useful. However, I am thinking if type of Key and Value are reference type, isn't Dictionary.Add() method only add the references into itself, instead of making a copy of the data that Key and Value refer to? In that sense, isn't it a shallow copy?

Comment: In that respect, then yes, you could consider it a shallow copy. The CLR's typing system does not call for automatic copy-constructors and implementing IClonable is entirely optional so you'll find deep-copies in the .NET world to be very rare, but fortunately there are very few reasons you'd want to do this: strings are immutable which is probably the #1 copied object type in the world.

Comment: @David Most of time we don't need deep copy, of course. But currently I frequently use it, for example, make deep copy of a collection and modify elements of the copy, then compare the copy with original collection for analytical reason. In these cases, it is extremely tedious to copy element by element every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d1 = d2;
d2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

This will in fact do the job. I don't see why this would not work. Dictionaries are reference types, so you won't copy them but just re-assign the reference if you do the above (exactly what you want to do).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Comment: Oh, is it? I thought after d1 = d2; d1 and d2 both references to same copy of data, and make d2 null will let d1 loses the data.

Comment: No if you do that you just set the reference of d2 to null. d1 will stay with its reference and the garbage collector won't collect the allocated memory since there still is an active reference to it so it will stay in memory.